# when table name include a DOT , JPA throw "INSERT command denied to user for table 'XXX'"

Tags: jpa, mariadb, ejb

I have a strange issue with JPA. I have renamed a table in my database from **"Users"** to **"App.Users"**. And put this annotation to my entity class: **@Table(name="App.Users")** then I got this error:

```
INSERT command denied to user 'XXXXX'@'XXXXX' for table 'Users'
```

I am using MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the chapter [Identifier names](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/identifier-names/) of MariaDB documentation.

Identifiers with characters which are not ANSI characters in the range [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_]  and which are not unicode characters >= 0x0080FF have to be quoted in backticks.

The decimal point in unquoted identifiers additionally has a special meaning: In your example it means schema/database "App" and table "Users". Since the user has no privileges on database App (event if it doesn't exist) a privilege error occurred.